# How to create a trust strategy that accepts only certificates with signed by a public authority?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x, java-6

Currently I have the following piece of code that accepts any SSL certificate (Apache HTTP client 4.5.7):

```
CloseableHttpClient client;
final SSLConnectionSocketFactory sf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(new TLSSocketConnectionFactory(),
        new String[]{"TLSv1.2"}, new String[]{}, new AnyHostnameVerifier(logger));


client = HttpClients
        .custom()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(sf)
        .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new AnyHostnameVerifier(logger))
        .setSSLContext(new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
                return true;
            }
        }).build())
        .build();
return client;
```

I want to create a similar client, which would

- accept any certificate that is signed by a public authority and
- reject self-signed certificates.

How can I do it?

**My attempt to do it**

As far as I know, if I use a default KeyStore, it will automatically verify the validity of a certificate signed by a public authority.

So I wrote this:

```
final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
```

But the method `SSLContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial` takes a second argument -- the trust strategy.

This is where I get stuck -- I have no idea how to implement a trust strategy that would fulfill the above criteria (accept all certificates signed by a public authority, reject all self-signed ones). Should I implement it at all or just pass `null`?

Comment: What you describe is the default behavior. Get rid of your insecure `TrustStrategy` implementation.

Comment: @user207421 You mean like `.setSSLContext(new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, null).build())`?